# Вывод runtime на русском в java

Tags: java

Добрый день. Помогите новичку...
 Пытаюсь парсить вывод утилиты Windows ping или tracert из java. Windows русскоязычная. 
 Проверял вывод в консоль и в файл. Вместо русских букв - знаки вопроса.
 Подозреваю, что дело в кодировке, но как решить эту проблему не пойму.
 Направьте в правильную сторону, плз. Почему так получается?

```
 Process p;
    String command = "ping 8.8.8.8";
    try {
        int coutn =0;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        p.waitFor();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("Ответ от")) {
                coutn++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(coutn);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле должна помочь
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394986/runtime-exec-command-with-utf-8-characters

Comment: @carapuz Пожалуйста, опубликуйте полный ответ. Уверен, автор вопроса будет благодарен за ваше экспертное мнение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В примере показано, как давать команду в кодировке UTF-8. Мне же нужно получить вывод в UTF-8. Пробовал line, которую я читаю из потока перекодировать, как в примере по ссылке. line = URLEncoder.encode(line, "utf-8"); Знаков вопроса нет, но все равно "абракадабра".

Comment: Я отправлял "одиночные" пинг-запросы и следил за "уровнем ошибки", как завершилось.
Меня, правда не интересовали сами числа из ответа. Меня устраивало просто "прошло-нет". Я просто по списку проверял, есть-ли связь с ПК. Если ДА - выполняем задание на нем, или идем дальше по списку.
Попробуйде при попытке перекодировки взять что-то подобное "ДОС"-кодировке. В win-блокноте это шрифт "terminal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь.

Оказалось нужно указывать кодировку так, что бы поток шел уже в нужной кодировке. Такой кодировкой оказалась в windows "Cp866".

Метод с одним пингом и кодом ошибки я пробовал. Работает не корректно, если я проверяю недоступный хост в той же сети. В таком случае этот способ даёт код ошибки "1". Как будто хост доступен. Для проверки шлюза даст не правильный результат. 
Можно, правда, добавить проверку на наличие поля TTL в ответе пинга. Тогда оно работает правильно. Тестировал как то так:

```
    Process p;
    String command = "ping -n 1 192.168.0.55 | find \\\"TTL\\\"\"";

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {


        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        int exitValue = p.waitFor();


        System.out.println(exitValue);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

В итоге для себя сделал следующим образом:

```
  public static boolean ping(String ip) {
    int coutn =0;
    boolean reachable = false;
    try {

        Process p;
        String command = "ping " + ip;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "Cp866"));

        p.waitFor();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if(line.startsWith("Ответ от")) {
                coutn++;
            }
        }
        if (coutn ==4) {
             reachable=true;
        }
        else {
             reachable=false;
        }
    }

    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return reachable;

}
```